# Passing Password as an argument to psql command in NSIS

Tags: postgresql, nsis

I am trying to pass an input password to a sql command in NSIS. 
If I run psql on command line, its like:

```
 psql -U postgres -v V1=username -v V2="'dbpassword'" -w -f "path\file.sql"
```

The sql file consists of the following relevant command:

```
CREATE USER :V1 WITH PASSWORD :V2 LOGIN NOSUPERUSER IN GROUP postgres;
```

How do I execute the same command in NSIS using variables? I tried the following but that won't work

```
nsExec::Exec 'psql -U postgres -v V1=$username -v V2=$dbpassword -w -f "path\file.sql"'
```

If I use `"'$dbpassword'"` it wont compile.

Comment: is `$dbpassword` a variable defined in your nsis script? What is the message given by `makensis.exe` when it does not compile?

Comment: yes. when I use -v V2=$dbpassword, it compiles. However when I run the script the user is not created(although it doesn't throw an error). But it doesnt compile and says : "Unterminated string parsing at line..." when I use -v V2="'$dbpassword'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quoting problem: when you try to put `-v V2="'$dbpassword'"` in your command

```
nsExec::Exec 'psql -U postgres -v V1=$username -v V2=$dbpassword -w -f "path\file.sql"'
```

It results in the following command with a string quoting mismatch:

```
nsExec::Exec 'psql -U postgres -v V1=$username -v V2="'$dbpassword'" -w -f "path\file.sql"'
             ^                                        ^
              `- Begining of string                    `- End of string
```

After the single quote following `V2`, the string is syntaxicaly terminated thus the following text is garbage for the compiler.

The trick is that NSIS can handle 3 different string delimiters : single quote `'`, double quote `"` and back quote `` ` ``.
Try to use back quote to avoid single / double quote collision in your command:

```
nsExec::Exec `psql -U postgres -v V1=$username -v V2="'$dbpassword'" -w -f "path\file.sql"`
```